# tikz-qtree with scope ? (how to draw the Cayley formula)

Tags: tikz-qtree, scoping

I want to make a tree for the Cayley formula as this :

[image]

(But with a vertical layout)

I can use the `tikz-qtree` environments as show in section 1 below

I can draw the graph as show in section 2

But if I try to put a graph as a node of the tree ... big bug !
Nodeway i use the scope tp put the sub-fig in the other !
But without success.

I can't find a anwser in this forum or with the Google-friend.

Here's a exemple :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]

\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{color,xcolor}
\usepackage{etex} % pour supprimer l'erreur 'No rom for new dim' avec tikz (avant Titz)
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{%                      
    ptn/.style={% node point for caeyley
                    circle, 
                    inner sep=0.7pt,
                    fill=black,
                    draw
                    },
    pthb/.style={% path black for caeyley
                    thin, draw=darkgray},   
    pthr/.style={% path red for caeyley
                    thick, draw=red},                                   
    }

\section{Tree only}


      \begin{tikzpicture}
      \tikzset{execute at begin node=\strut}
      \tikzset{level distance=40pt}   
      \tikzset{frontier/.style ={distance from root=120pt}}
      \tikzset{edge from parent/.append style= %
      {draw,edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) -- +(0,-8pt) -| (\tikzchildnode)}}
      }   
      \Tree 
      [.Root 
        [.A 
            [.AA BB CC ] C  
            ] 
        [.B BB  
        ] 
      ]
    \end{tikzpicture}  


\section{Graph only}

        \begin{tikzpicture}%
        [x=5mm, y=5mm, semithick,every loop/.style={max distance = 2mm,looseness=60}]
        \node[ptn] (a) at (0,0) {};
        \node[ptn] (b) at (0,1) {};
        \node[ptn] (c) at (1,0) {};
        \node[ptn] (d) at (1,1) {};                               
        \path[pthb] 
        (a) edge (b) edge (c) 
        (d) edge (b) edge (c);
        \path[pthr] (a) edge (d);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\section{Graph in the tree ?}   

      \begin{tikzpicture}
      \tikzset{execute at begin node=\strut}
      \tikzset{level distance=40pt}   
      \tikzset{frontier/.style ={distance from root=120pt}} 
      \tikzset{edge from parent/.append style= % 
      {draw,edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) -- +(0,-8pt) -| (\tikzchildnode)}}
      \tikzset{every loop/.style={max distance = 2mm,looseness=60}}
      }   
      \Tree 
      [.\begin{scope}%[x=3mm,y=3mm,semithick]
        \node[ptn] (a) at (0,0) {};
        \node[ptn] (b) at (0,1) {};
        \node[ptn] (c) at (1,0) {};
        \node[ptn] (d) at (1,1) {};                               
        \path[pthb] 
        (a) edge (b) edge (c) edge (d)
        (d) edge (b) edge (c);
      \end{scope}   
        [.A 
            [.AA BB CC ] C  
            ] 
        [.B BB  
        ] 
      ]
    \end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: You code doesn't compile; please correct it.

Comment: I know it doen't work, it's my question ;-) If you comment the tikz in section 3 you can compile the section 1 and 2, but the problem is precisely to make the graph at section 3 ... where it bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you write `\begin{scope}` you are already inside a node. Here TikZ macros are deactivated. You will need the `tikzpicture` environment around it.

Though, I would go another approach and use simple nodes with `append after command`. The idea is taken from [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141199/16595) to [Graphs in commutative diagrams in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141156/16595).

Another approach would be to use a `\matrix` at the place of a node (which is just a node from the type `matrix`) where on can place arbitrary TikZ code in it.

I use `forest` here but if you can easily access the nodes in `tikz-qtree` the same approach should be applicable.

---

It has been reported that the code shown below does not work with TikZ’s official 2.10 version. This can be solved by replacing the `\tikzset{aac/.style=…` command with

```
\forestset{append after command/.style={tikz={%
  \path[late options={name=\forestoption{name},append after command={#1}}];}},
  aac/.style={
    append after command={[shift=(\tikzlastnode.center),
      x={($(\tikzlastnode.east)-(\tikzlastnode.center)$)},
      y={($(\tikzlastnode.north)-(\tikzlastnode.center)$)}, #1]}}}
```

making both `append after command` and `aac` a `/forest` style.

---

It should be noted that the options given with the `shift`, the `x` and the `y` key can also be expressed without `calc`’s notation if PGF macros are used, i.e.:

```
\pgfextra{\pgftransformshift{\pgfpointanchor{\tikzlastnode}{center}}%
  \pgfsetxvec{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{\tikzlastnode}{center}}
             {\pgfpointanchor{\tikzlastnode}{east}}}%
  \pgfsetyvec{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{\tikzlastnode}{center}}
             {\pgfpointanchor{\tikzlastnode}{north}}}}
```

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\tikzset{aac/.style={
    append after command={[shift=(\tikzlastnode.center),% every edge/.append style={opacity=.5},
      x={($(\tikzlastnode.east)-(\tikzlastnode.center)$)},
      y={($(\tikzlastnode.north)-(\tikzlastnode.center)$)}, #1]}}}
\tikzset{
  dot/.style={shape=circle,fill,draw,inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+2pt},
  % squares
  square/.style={insert path={\foreach \a[count=\c] in {45,135,225,315}{(\a:.7) node[dot] (s-\c) {}}}},
  square U/.style={square,insert path={(s-3) edge (s-4) edge (s-2) (s-4) edge (s-1)}},
  square O/.style={square U, insert path={(s-1) edge (s-2)}},
  square Oslash/.style={square O, insert path={(s-2) edge (s-4)}},
  % triangles (the yshift is not good)
  triangle/.style={yshift=+1.5pt, insert path={\foreach \a[count=\c] in {30, 150, 270} {(\a:.7) node[dot] (t-\c) {}}}},
  triangle V/.style={triangle, insert path={(t-3) edge (t-1) edge (t-2)}},
  triangle full/.style={triangle V, insert path={(t-1) edge (t-2)}},
  % ring2
  ring2/.style={insert path={edge[to path={circle [radius=.5]}]() (up:.5) coordinate[dot] (r2-1) (down:.5) coordinate[dot] (r2-2)}},
  % ring3
  ring3/.style={insert path={(0,0) coordinate (r3-1) (left:.7) coordinate (r3-2) (right:.7) coordinate (r3-3)}},
  ring3 o.o/.style={ring3, insert path={
    (r3-1) edge[to path={arc[radius=.35, start angle=0,   delta angle=360]}] ()
           edge[to path={arc[radius=.35, start angle=180, delta angle=360]}] ()
           node[dot]{}}},
  ring3 .o.o/.style={ring3 o.o, insert path={(r3-2) node[dot]{}}},
  ring3 .o.o./.style={ring3 .o.o, insert path={(r3-3) node[dot]{}}},
  ring3 o.-./.style={ring3, insert path={
    (r3-1) coordinate[dot] (@) edge[to path={arc[radius=.35, start angle=0, delta angle=360]}] ()
                       (r3-3) node[dot] {} edge (@)}},
  ring3 .o.-./.style={ring3 o.-., insert path={(r3-2) node[dot]{}}},
  % misc
  just a line/.style={insert path={(left:.75) coordinate[dot] (@) (right:.75) node[at end, dot]{} edge (@)}}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest} for tree={node options={minimum size=+15pt}},
[,aac=square Oslash
  [,aac=ring3 .o.o.
    [,aac=ring3 .o.o
      [,aac=ring3 o.-.]
      [,aac=ring3 o.o]
    ]
    [,aac=ring3 .o.-.
      [,rotate=-90, aac={ring3 o.-.}]
      [,aac=triangle V]
    ]
  ]
  [,aac=square O
    [,aac=square U]
    [,aac=triangle full
      [,aac=ring2
        [,aac=ring3 o.o]
        [,aac=just a line]
      ]
      [,aac=triangle V]
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! I've recently discover this package 'forest' too

Comment: If I try your code i get 101 errors. Most of them are "Pgf Error: No shape named ... is known"

Comment: @madit I don’t get any errors with the CVS version of TikZ but with the stable version. Looks like somehow `\tikzlastnode` from `append after command` is accessed too early (before the node actually exists or is drawn) and that throws everything off. (See `forest`’s `label` option for more discussion on this.) I don’t know how to solve this with `forest` options …

Comment: @madit See my updated answer.

Comment: Ok I see the comments. And it works now with replacing in your code the first tikzset by forestset (and adding an \end{document}. Thank you !!!

Comment: But I don't understand witch part I can replace by the macro pgf...