# Graphs in commutative diagrams in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, graphs

I want to draw a diamond shape commutative diagram using tikz. Instead of just letters I want to have simple graphs (just edges and vertices) in the diagram. 
I tried some stuff but the diagram still looks superugly. Is there any way to make this look smoother?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}

     \begin{document}

       \begin{center}
         \begin{tikzcd}
          & 
          \begin{tikzpicture}%B
        [every node/.style={circle,fill=black,inner sep=3pt}]
          \node (a) at (0,0) {};
          \node (b) at (0,-1)  {};
          \node[olive] (d) at (1,0)  {};
          \node[olive] (f) at (0,1)  {};

          \foreach \from/\to in {a/b,a/d,a/f}
            \draw (\from) -- (\to);
        \end{tikzpicture}
         \arrow{dr} &\\

          \begin{tikzpicture}%A
        [every node/.style={circle,fill=black, inner sep=3pt}]
          \node (a) at (0,0.5) {};
          \node (b) at (0,-0.5)  {};

          \foreach \from/\to in {a/b}
            \draw (\from) -- (\to);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \arrow{ur} \arrow{dr} & &
        \begin{tikzpicture}%Amalgam
        [every node/.style={circle,fill=black, inner sep=3pt}]
          \node (a) at (1,1) {};
          \node (b) at (1,0)  {};
          \node[orange] (c) at (0.125,0.5) {};
          \node[olive] (d) at (2,1)  {};
          \node[orange] (e) at (1.7,1.7) {};
          \node[olive] (f) at (1,2)  {};

          \foreach \from/\to in {a/b, a/c,a/d,a/e,a/f,c/b}
            \draw (\from) -- (\to);
        \end{tikzpicture}\\
         &
         \begin{tikzpicture}%C
        [every node/.style={circle,fill=black, inner sep=3pt}]
          \node (a) at (1,1) {};
          \node (b) at (1,0)  {};
          \node[orange] (c) at (0.125,0.5) {};
          \node[orange] (e) at (1.7,1.7) {};

          \foreach \from/\to in {a/b,a/c,a/e,c/b}
            \draw (\from) -- (\to);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \arrow{ur}
        &\\
         \end{tikzcd}
        \end{center}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Could you turn your snippet into a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)- it really helps that wish to look at your code and help with your problem :) Welcome!

Comment: This MWE will not compile for me.  Are you sure you copied it correctly?

Comment: @Charles StaatsI just tried it and it works for me.

Comment: What is the desired output supposed to look like?

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[   every node/.style={circle,inner sep=2.5pt,fill=black,outer sep=0pt},
    hull/.style={draw=gray!20,fill=none,inner sep=0.6cm},
    scale=0.5,
]
    %B
    \begin{scope}[shift={(30:6)}]
    \node (a) at (0,0) {};
    \node (b) at (0,-1)  {};
    \node[olive] (d) at (1,0)  {};
    \node[olive] (f) at (0,1)  {};
    \foreach \to in {b,d,f} \draw (a) -- (\to);
    \node[hull] (B) at (0,0) {};
  \end{scope}
  %A
  \begin{scope}[shift={(0:0)}]
    \node (a) at (0,0) {};
    \node (b) at (0,-1)  {};
    \draw (a) -- (b);
    \node[hull] (A) {};
    \end{scope}     
    %Amalgam
  \begin{scope}[shift={(0:{12*cos(30)})}]
    \node (a) at (0,0) {};
    \node (b) at (0,-1)  {};
    \node[orange] (c) at (-0.866,-0.5) {};
    \node[olive] (d) at (1,0)  {};
    \node[orange] (e) at (0.707,0.707) {};
    \node[olive] (f) at (0,1) {};
    \foreach \from/\to in {a/b, a/c, a/d, a/e, a/f, c/b} \draw (\from) -- (\to);
    \node[hull] (Amalgam) at (0,0) {};
  \end{scope}
  %C
    \begin{scope}[shift={(-30:6)}]
    \node (a) at (0,0) {};
    \node (b) at (0,-1)  {};
    \node[orange] (c) at (-0.866,-0.5) {};
    \node[orange] (e) at (0.707,0.707) {};
    \foreach \from/\to in {a/b, a/c, a/e, c/b} \draw (\from) -- (\to);
    \node[hull] (C) at (0,0) {};
    \end{scope}
    \foreach \from/\to in {A/B, A/C, B/Amalgam, C/Amalgam} \draw[-latex] (\from) -- (\to);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [Tom Bombadil](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/7279/tom-bombadil)’s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141175/16595) but very much different.

First of all: Nesting TikZ pictures is a bad idea. With a basic TikZ matrix, you could however put a mini-picture consisting of nodes and path in a cell. However, you cannot reference the whole cell.

In this solution a `container` node style is created that while later serve as the root nodes of our diagram. Each container will use the `aac` style to use a special setup of the `append after command` style. The setup is a special local coordinate system which center is at the center of the node and the *x* and *y* vectors point to the `east` and `north` anchor respectively. This allows the local coordinate system to transform and especially rotate with the root node. We could have also just used the `my Size` value to setup the coordinate system or used a `path picture` or …

The `settings` key contains basic options for our mini-pictures in the containers. Then the three keys `base`, `top` and `bottom` configure the parts of the mini-pictures. These are then used with the `aac` key to built the mini-picture.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\tikzset{aac/.style={
    append after command={[shift=(\tikzlastnode.center),
      x={($(\tikzlastnode.east)-(\tikzlastnode.center)$)},
      y={($(\tikzlastnode.north)-(\tikzlastnode.center)$)}, #1]}}}
\tikzset{
  my Size/.initial=+3mm, my distance/.initial=.6,
  declare function={my_dist=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/my distance};},
  container/.style={shape=circle, draw=gray, inner sep=+0pt, label={#1},
    minimum size={8*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/my Size})}},
  settings/.style={every edge/.append style={-},
    nodes={draw, fill, shape=circle, inner sep=+0pt,
      minimum size=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/my Size}}},
  base/.style={insert path={[settings]
    node (b1)                  {}
    node (b2) at (-90:my_dist) {} edge (b1)}},
  top/.style={insert path={
    node[olive] (t1) at (90:my_dist) {} edge (b1)
    node[olive] (t2) at ( 0:my_dist) {} edge (b1)}},
  bottom/.style={insert path={
    node[orange] (bo1) at (-90-60:my_dist) {} edge (b1) edge (b2)
    node[orange] (bo2) at (    45:my_dist) {} edge (b1)}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick, node distance=+.25cm and +1.5cm, latex-]
  \node[container=base,           aac=base]                         (l) {};
  \node[container={base and top}, aac={base,top}, above right=of l] (t) {}  edge (l);
  \node[container=below:{base and bottom}, aac={base,bottom}, below right=of l] (b) {}
                                                                            edge (l);
  \node[container=all, aac={base,bottom,top}, below right=of t] {} edge (t) edge (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I dont know if I already understood how this worked but this looks so much better. thanks!